# Magento. How to set data for custom options(checkbox) programatically and add simple product in cart?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Here is how i set data for custom options of simple product

```
     $arrProducts = array(
        array(
            "product_id" => 8,
            "qty" => 1,
            "options" => array(
                '1' => 'cheese',
                '2' => 'tomato'
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

but i receive an error

**Please specify the product required option(s).**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the data in little bit different: 
[please see explain here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9480/creating-custom-option-on-product-save).

[and here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16874/issue-when-programmatically-creating-custom-product-options) .

Good Luck!